# necessary and sufficient conditions so that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $p(x)=x^2+rx+s$ and $q(x)=x^2+tx+u$ be irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. If $p(\alpha)=q(\beta)=0$ for some $\alpha, \beta \notin \mathbb{Q}$, I need to find necessary and sufficient conditions on the coefficients that guarantee $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ are isomorphic.

My work

Since $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are irreducible polynomials, then we have

$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(q(x))$

If $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x)) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(q(x))$.

Can I conclude that $p(x)=q(x)$? if not, is there any relation between the two polynomials?

Comment: $x^2-3$ and $x^2-12$  as example?

Comment: @orangeskid, I think this example shows that the two field are equal, right? For isomorphism, they always isomorphic, right?

Comment: Yes, so the discriminants differ multiplicatively by the square of a rational number. This is a necessary condition in higher degree $n$ too, it turns out it is also sufficient if $n=2$.

Comment: Two finite dimensional **Galois** extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$, both sitting inside $\Bbb{C}$, are isomorphic if and only if they are equal. This happens always in the quadratic case, as all quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ are Galois. If we drop the Galois assumption, this is no longer true, the fields gotten by adjoing one of the roots of $x^3-2$  is possibly the simplest example.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I think this works out because we can assume two such isomorphic extensions $K, L$ with $K=\mathbb{Q} (a) $ and $m(x) \in\mathbb{Q} [x] $ the minimal polynomial of $a$ and $\sigma:K\to L$ the isomorphism. Then $b=\sigma(a) $ is also a root of $m(x) $ and $K$ being Galois we have $b\in K$. Thus $L=\sigma(K) \subseteq K$. Reversing the roles of $K, L$ we get $K\subseteq L$.

Comment: That's the argument @ParamanandSingh. An alternative end game is to observe that $\sigma(K)$ and $K$ have the same dimension as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$, so one way inclusion suffices to give equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_1})$ where $d_1=r^2-4s.$ Similarly, $\Bbb Q(\beta)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_2})$ where $d_2=t^2-4u.$

If these two fields are isomorphic then $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_2})$ contains a square root of $d_1,$ i.e.

$$\exists a,b\in\Bbb Q,\quad d_1=(a+b\sqrt{d_2})^2=a^2+b^2d_2+2ab\sqrt{d_2}$$
i.e. $d_1=a^2+b^2d_2$ and $ab=0.$
Since $d_1$ is not a square in $\Bbb Q,$ $b$ cannot be $0.$ Therefore, $a=0$ and
$$d_1=b^2d_2.$$

We thus proved that if $\Bbb Q(\alpha)\cong\Bbb Q(\beta)$ then $d_1=b^2d_2$ for some $b\in\Bbb Q.$ The converse being obvious, we can conclude:

$$\Bbb Q(\alpha)\cong\Bbb Q(\beta)\iff\exists b\in\Bbb Q,\quad\frac{r^2-4s}{t^2-4u}=b^2.$$