# Prove that $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\pi7)\neq\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\pi9)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cubics, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\tau=2\pi$ be the full angle. ([tau](https://tauday.com/tau-manifesto))

For any integer $k$ and any angle $\theta$, $\cos(k\theta)$ is a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) in $\cos\theta$. In particular, $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2\theta-1$, which shows that $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau n)\subseteq\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2n})$. Furthermore, if $n$ is odd, then $\cos(\tfrac\tau{2n})=-\cos(\tfrac\tau2-\tfrac\tau{2n})=-\cos(\tfrac{n-1}2\tfrac\tau n)$, which shows that $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2n})\subseteq\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau n)$, so the fields are equal: $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau n)=\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\pi n)$.

$x=2\cos\tfrac\tau9$ has minimal polynomial $x^3-3x+1=0$, and $y=2\cos\tfrac\tau7$ has minimal polynomial $y^3+y^2-2y-1=0$. These can be gotten from cyclotomic polynomials, using $2\cos\theta=e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}$.

I tried writing $y=ax^2+bx+c$ with rational $a,b,c$, but that led to a mess of $3$ cubic equations in $3$ variables; I see no way to tell whether a solution exists:

$$0x^2+0x+0=y^3+y^2-2y-1$$
$$=\Big(9a^3 + 9ab^2 + 9a^2c - 3a^2b + 3ac^2 + 3b^2c + 3a^2 + b^2 + 2ac - 2a\Big)x^2 \\ +\Big(-6a^3 - 3ab^2 - 3a^2c + 27a^2b + 18abc + 3b^3 + 3bc^2 - a^2 + 6ab + 2bc - 2b\Big)x \\ +\Big(a^3 - 9a^2b - 6abc - b^3 + c^3 - 2ab + c^2 - 2c - 1\Big).$$

How else can we show that $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau7)\neq\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau9)$?

I know that the cyclotomic fields $\mathbb Q(e^{i\tau/(2n)})$ are all distinct for $n\in\mathbb N$. (See Theorem 4.1 in [Keith Conrad's notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf).) But their real subfields $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2n})$ are not all distinct; for $n=1,2,3$ they are just $\mathbb Q$. Maybe for $n>3$ they are distinct?

Comment: Try computing the discriminant of each field (which is closely related to the discriminant of the polynomial).

Comment: The last link has been updated to address this question. See the new Theorem 4.3 there.

Comment: @KCd - So we know that the fields are not equal, as subsets of $\mathbb R$. But can they be isomorphic? You characterized the $2n$th cyclotomic field by the number of roots of unity (of any order). Maybe the real subfield can be characterized by the number of elements with the same minimal polynomial as $2\cos(\tau/n)$ for some $n$.

Comment: They are not isomorphic, by Galois theory.  If $M/\mathbf Q$ is an abelian extension and $K$ and $L$ are two subfields of $M$ that are isomorphic, then the subgroups ${\rm Gal}(M/K)$ and ${\rm Gal}(M/L)$ of ${\rm Gal}(M/\mathbf Q)$ are conjugate.  In an abelian group, conjugate subgroups must be equal, so ${\rm Gal}(M/K) = {\rm Gal}(M/L)$. Then $K = L$ by the Galois correspondence. Apply this to $K = \mathbf Q(\zeta_m + \zeta_m^{-1})$, $L = \mathbf Q(\zeta_n+ \zeta_n^{-1})$, and $M = \mathbf Q(\zeta_{mn})$ to see that if $K \cong L$ then $K = L$.

Comment: More generally, when $F$ is a field with algebraic closure $\overline{F}$, two abelian Galois extensions of $F$ in $\overline{F}$ that are $F$-isomorphic must be equal. (Fields of characteristic $0$ that are isomorphic are $\mathbf Q$-isomorphic, so I did not need to speak about $\mathbf Q$-isomorphisms explicitly in my previous comment.)

Comment: Regarding isomorphism of these fields see the discussion in comments under https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4738389/72031

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=2\cos(2\pi/9),b=2\cos(2\pi/7)$ and let $f(x) =x^3-3x+1$,$g(x)=x^3+x^2-2x-1$ be minimal polynomials of $a, b$ respectively and let $K=\mathbb{Q} (a), L=\mathbb{Q} (b) $.

We have $$\text{disc} (f(x)) =\text{disc} (\mathbb{Z} [a])=([O_K:\mathbb{Z} [a]]) ^2\text{disc}(O_K)$$ and then $$81=([O_K:\mathbb{Z} [a]]) ^2\text{disc}(O_K)$$ It follows that $$[O_K:\mathbb{Z} [a]] = 1, 3,\text{ or }9$$ and hence $$\text{disc} (O_K) =1, 9,\text{ or }81$$ But $\text{disc} (O_K) \neq 1$ as $K\neq \mathbb{Q} $ we have $\text{disc} (O_K) =9 \text{ or } 81$.

In same fashion using $$\text{disc} (g(x)) =\text{disc} (\mathbb{Z} [b])=([O_L:\mathbb{Z} [b]]) ^2\text{disc}(O_L)$$ we get $\text {disc} (O_L) =49$. It follows that $K\neq L$ as the discriminants of these fields are not same.

Answer (score 1):

According to the previous Theorem (3.4) in those notes,

$$\mathbb Q(e^{i\tau/m})\cap\mathbb Q(e^{i\tau/n})=\mathbb Q(e^{i\tau/\text{GCD}(m,n)}).$$

Intersecting with $\mathbb R$, we get

$$\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau m)\cap\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau n)=\mathbb Q\big(\cos\tfrac\tau{\text{GCD}(m,n)}\big).$$

Suppose $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2m})=\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2n})$ where $m\geq n>3$, and let $g=\text{GCD}(m,n)$. We have $\text{GCD}(2m,2n)=2g$. The field's intersection with itself is itself, so

$$\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2m})=\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2n})=\mathbb Q\big(\cos\tfrac\tau{2g}\big).$$

Taking degrees over $\mathbb Q$, if $g=1$ then

$$\tfrac12\phi(2m)=\tfrac12\phi(2n)=1$$

which is impossible since $\phi(2n)>2$ when $2n>6$. If $g>1$ then

$$\tfrac12\phi(2m)=\tfrac12\phi(2n)=\tfrac12\phi(2g),$$

and since $m$ and $n$ are multiples of $g$, the totients $\phi(2m)$ and $\phi(2n)$ are multiples of $\phi(2g)$. Any extra factor of $2$ in $2n$, compared to $2g$, would contribute a factor of $2$ to the totient, thus making $\phi(2n)>\phi(2g)$. Any extra odd prime factor $p$ in $2n$ would contribute either $p$ or $p-1$ to the totient, again making $\phi(2n)>\phi(2g)$. Therefore, we must have $n=g$, and similarly $m=g$, so $m=n$.

(For the specific case in the OP, take $m=9$ and $n=7$.)

Answer (score -1):

The minimal polynomial of $x=\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{9}\right)$ and of $x=\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)$ are $f(x)=8x^3-6x-1$ and $g(x)=8x^3-4x^2-4x+1$ respectively. It follows that the two irrational numbers are of third degree but distinct and $\mathbb Q$-linear independant so $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\pi7)\neq\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\pi9)$. What happen is similar, say, to the cases $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ in degree two.

NOTE.-A derived problem, equivalent to this answer, could be, a good exercise for beginners:

**Prove that for all triple of rational $(a,b,c)$ one has** $$a\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{9}\right)+b\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{9}\right)^2+c\ne \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)$$

Comment: Being linearly independent over rationals doesn't really show that the two fields are different. The problem here is really equivalent to the one mentioned at end of answer but they are not related to linear independence. The linear independence thing however works for quadratic irrationals.

Comment: "Prove that [...]" - I already tried to do that in the OP. How do you prove it?