# Can three antiprisms (uniform polyhedra) fit exactly around an edge, leaving no gaps?

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory, polyhedra, cyclotomic-fields, algebraic-numbers

[Let $\tau=2\pi$](https://tauday.com/tau-manifesto) $=360^\circ$.

An $n$-gon [antiprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiprism#Uniform_antiprism) has dihedral angles

$$\theta_n = \arccos\left(-\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac\tau{4n}\right)$$

(where an $n$-gon meets a triangle) and

$$\phi_n = 2\arccos\left(\frac2{\sqrt3}\sin\frac\tau{4n}\right)$$
$$=\arccos\left(-\frac13\left(4\cos\frac\tau{2n}-1\right)\right)$$

(where two triangles meet). As $n$ increases from $3$ (the triangular antiprism being the Platonic octahedron), $\theta_n$ decreases from $\arccos({-\tfrac13})\approx109^\circ$ and approaches $\tfrac\tau4=90^\circ$, and $\phi_n$ increases from $\arccos({-\tfrac13})\approx109^\circ$ and approaches $\tfrac\tau2=180^\circ$.

Are there integers $l,m,n\geq3$ such that

$$\theta_l + \theta_m + \phi_n = \tau \; ?$$

---

If two polyhedra are required to have the same type of face where they touch, then we must have $l=m$. (And the other faces are all triangles, so there's no problem.) The equation becomes $2\theta_m + \phi_n = \tau$.

$$\theta_m=\frac\tau2-\frac{\phi_n}2$$
$$\cos\theta_m=-\cos\frac{\phi_n}2$$
$$-\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan\frac\tau{4m}=-\frac2{\sqrt3}\sin\frac\tau{4n}$$
$$\tan^2\frac\tau{4m}=4\sin^2\frac\tau{4n}$$
$$\frac{1-\cos\frac\tau{2m}}{1+\cos\frac\tau{2m}}=2\left(1-\cos\frac\tau{2n}\right)$$

This last equation can be solved for either cosine in terms of the other cosine. Thus $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2m})=\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\tau{2n})$. But such fields are never equal unless $m=n$. ( [Prove that $\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\pi7)\neq\mathbb Q(\cos\tfrac\pi9)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749611/prove-that-mathbb-q-cos-tfrac-pi7-neq-mathbb-q-cos-tfrac-pi9) ) Then the middle equation gives $\sec\tfrac\tau{4m}=2$, so $m=3/2$ which isn't an integer. (Anyway, the $3/2$ (crossed) antiprism is worse than non-convex; it's planar, with all faces coinciding.)

---

It remains to consider the case $l\neq m$.

$$\cos(\theta_l+\theta_m)=\cos(\tau-\phi_n)$$
$$\cos\theta_l\cos\theta_m-\sin\theta_l\sin\theta_m=\cos\phi_n$$
$$(\cos\theta_l\cos\theta_m-\cos\phi_n)^2=(1-\cos^2\theta_l)(1-\cos^2\theta_m)$$
$$-2\cos\theta_l\cos\theta_m\cos\phi_n+\cos^2\phi_n+\cos^2\theta_l+\cos^2\theta_m=1$$
$$\frac29\tan\frac\tau{4l}\tan\frac\tau{4m}\left(4\cos\frac\tau{2n}-1\right)+\frac13\tan^2\frac\tau{4l}+\frac13\tan^2\frac\tau{4m}+\frac19\left(4\cos\frac\tau{2n}-1\right)^2=1$$

Comment: However, m=l=2 (tetrahedra) and n=3 (octahedron) would be an according solution.

Comment: $m=2$ gives a dihedral angle of $125^\circ$, which a tetrahedron does not have. That's why I restricted $l,m,n\geq3$.

Comment: The digonal antiprism, of course, has two digon faces, and is thus not a proper convex polyhedron. The angle $125^\circ$ is between a digon and a triangle. I suppose your solution could be allowed, if we generalized this question to non-convex antiprisms, with rational $l,m,n>3/2$.